# Cookie settings dialog spells the same word in both American and British English in different places

Tags: feature-request, wording, cookie-consent-dialog

In the Cookie Settings, specifically under the "Privacy Preference Center" section, I've noticed a discrepancy in language usage related to personalization. The term "personalized" is predominantly used, which aligns with American English (en-US), while under the "Functional Cookies" section, the term "personalisation" is used, which is more in line with British English (en-GB), commonly used in the UK, AU, and NZ.

I suggest ensuring consistency in language usage across all sections. Would it be possible to standardize on one term, either "personalized" or "personalisation"?

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Consistency in Language Usage in Cookie Settings]

Comment: I believe [the standard is to use American spelling](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#use-american-spelling-and-standards) for text written by the company. This text may be provided by a third party for a European audience though.